# How to install workrave on a Debian based distro?

Tags: installation, debian

I wanted to install an application to prevent repetitive strain injury.

I tried workrave, but it does not install. I do not know how to compile the source. Is it possible to do something about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dont worry about compiling just download the latest [installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/workrave/files/latest/download?source=files) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/workrave/files/

Try to install workrave, type the following command under Debian / Ubuntu Linux, enter:

```
sudo apt-get install workrave
```

Workrave works as an applet - a small application whose user interface resides within a panel. You need to add workrave to the panel to control it.

Adding a New Workrave Object To Panel:

1. Right-click on a vacant space on a panel to open the panel popup menu.
2. Choose Add to Panel.
3. The Add to Panel dialog opens.The available panel objects are listed alphabetically, with launchers at the top. Select workrave applet and click on Add button.

[image]

*if it doesn't work please report the error message.*

Comment: Hey is that ubuntu 12.04? It looks like a much older version of ubuntu. Anyway, I tried `sudo apt-get install workrave` and I get a message that says `E: Package 'workrave' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: yes I'm on Win7 atm, copied the image. That error message looks quite common.. google came up with a bunch of answers. Good luck.

Comment: Hey I used the source from sourceforge. Thanks for the help mate :)

Comment: works for me now (installs on 12.04)